# How to use different env config for phpunit in Symfony application?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When trying to run a test in a separate environment the wrong doctrine configuration is being loaded. In phpunit.xml I have the following config:

```xml
<env name="APP_ENV" value="phpunit" force="true" />
```

Also specific doctrine config for this environment config/packages/phpunit/doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: test
        connections:
            test:
                dbname: '%env(PHPUNIT_DB_NAME)%'
                host: '%env(PHPUNIT_DB_HOST)%'
                port: '%env(PHPUNIT_DB_PORT)%'
                user: '%env(PHPUNIT_DB_USER)%'
                password: '%env(PHPUNIT_DB_PASSWORD)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: api_test
        entity_managers:
            api_test:
                connection: test
                mappings:
                    App:
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/ApiEntity'
                        prefix: 'App\ApiEntity'
```

And .env.phpunit

```
PHPUNIT_DB_HOST=mysql
PHPUNIT_DB_PORT=3306
PHPUNIT_DB_USER=root
PHPUNIT_DB_PASSWORD=root
PHPUNIT_DB_NAME=test
```

When running the test get the error that "Environment variable not found" from config/packages/doctrine.yaml is not being found.

Answer (score 0):

Look maybe for .env.test . See here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html